# When I click the play button the pause button disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sidebar with some songs and on each song there is the title and artist name and a play button. When I click on the play button the song starts playing (so far everything is ok) but the pause button should appear, instead when I click on the play button the pause button is shown.

```js
function populateTracklist() {
    let allList = document.querySelector('#tracklist');

    tracks.forEach((track, index)=> {
        let card = document.createElement('div');
        card.classList.add('col-12');
        card.innerHTML =
        `
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between px-4 py-3 border-main track-card">
            <img class="img_size" src="${track.cover}" alt="">
            <div class="text-white">
                <h5 class="mb-0 tx-gradient">${track.artist}</h5>
                <p class="mb-0">${track.title}</p>
            </div>
            <i data-track="${index}" class="fas fa-play fs-3 tx-gradient pointer playlist-play"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-pause fs-3 tx-gradient pointer"></i> 
        </div>
        `
        allList.appendChild(card);
    })
    let btnsPlay = document.querySelectorAll('.playlist-play');
     btnsPlay.forEach(btn=> {
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            let selectedTrack = btn.getAttribute('data-track');
            trackcurr = selectedTrack;
            changeTrackDetails();

            if (playing) {
                playing=false;
                play();
            }
            //console.log(trackcurr);
            //console.log(btn.parentNode);
            btn.parentNode.classList.add('active');
        })
     })
}
```

```css
.border-main{
    border-bottom: solid 4px var(--main);
}

.track-card.active{
    background: linear-gradient(var(--black) 90%, var(--sec));
}

.track-card .fa-pause{
    display: none;
}  

.track-card.active .fa-play{
    display: none;
}  

.track-card.active{
    display: block;
} 

.border-main.active{
    border-bottom: solid 4px var(--sec);
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarmusic" class="open">
        <div class="row" id="tracklist">
            <div class="col-12">                
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You access the play button with `document.querySelectorAll('.playlist-play');`. The pause button does not have the `.playlist-play` class, so it won't be included. The pause button is styled to have `display:none`. You'll need to access the pause button via an appropriate selector and change the display attribute to make it show conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

You can add id attribute to your play and pause button.

```
id='play-${index}'
id='pause-${index}'

//so that on your event listener
//you can simply get the element via id.

let pause = document.querySelector(`#pause-${selectedTrack}`)

//then remove the class

pause.classList.remove("fa-pause")

//or toggle 

pause.classList.toggle("fa-pause")
```

sorry for typo.. i am on mobile.